# Exporting rosbag playback visualization to video

Tags: rviz, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the best way to record a video of rviz during rosbag playback?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11784/exporting-rosbag-playback-visualization-to-video/) by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3838 on 2011-11-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest following this [RecordingOpenGLAppsWithGLC](http://www.ros.org/wiki/RecordingOpenGLAppsWithGLC) tutorial to learn how to record rviz, gazebo and other OpenGL applications.

---

Originally posted by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) with karma: 674 on 2011-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use [gtk-recordmydesktop](http://sourceforge.net/projects/recordmydesktop/files/gtk-recordMyDesktop/) mostly. There's also [Istanbul](http://live.gnome.org/Istanbul) and [XVidCap](http://xvidcap.sourceforge.net/). Gtk-recordmydesktop had the best performance in my opinion, since running Rviz + screen capture software has the potential to be very computationally intensive.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-11-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2